# Socket connection in java 8 springboot server

Tags: java, sockets, spring-boot, java-8

We have an old application built using java 6. It communicates via Sockets using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream.

//Code snippet to write to the stream

```
public void writeMessage(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    int pageSize = 10;  
    logger.info("pageSize: " + pageSize);
    out.writeInt(pageSize);
}
```

//Code snippet to read from the stream

```
public void readMessage(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    int pageSize = in.readInt();    
    logger.info("pageSize: " + pageSize);
}
```

It used to run in jboss as the application server with postgres as the DB.
Now we have migrated the application to springboot. It uses the embedded tomcat server and the same postgres DB.

The code is not reading from the stream correctly. I get `java.io.EOFException` when I call `in.readInt()`

Note: We use SSL/TLSv1 and certificates and keystores are properly setup.
There are no exceptions when the socket connection is established and when I write to the stream. 
Also, All Streams/Socket connections have been closed properly and the same code works fine in the jboss server.

EDIT: I tried using just `InputStream` or `BufferedInputStream` instead of `DataInputStream` and the results are even more confusing.

Let's say I send 20 bytes to the stream:
With `inputStream.read` only 1 byte is read and it reaches EOF prematurely.
With `bufferedInputStream.read` 19 bytes are read and 1 byte is missed.

I am using inputStream OR bufferedInputStream, not one after the other.

Please let me know if there is something I might be missing.

Comment: any suggestions please..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out the solution. It seems Java has changed the jsse security after 1.6

The solution was to add a property

> -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false

Something similar is mentioned [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/java-sql-sqlexception-i-o-error-connection-reset-when-connecting-to-an-external-sql-server-2008-database-284365810.html) where people were facing issues with SQL connection and suggested either changing java versions or adding this property.